# Get selected row in Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have problem with getting information which row of DT has been selected.
in a standard situation we define a table:

```
output$table <- renderUI({
   datatable(data)
})
```

And then by using `input$table_rows_selected` I get row number which has beeen selected.
But how do it in situation when we define table using dynamic name of it:

```
output[[variable$table]] <- renderDT({
   datatable(data)
})
```

I tried `input[[variable$table]]_rows_selected` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the name on the fly and subset `input` using `[[`.

See this reproducible example -

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

var <- 'dt_table'

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput(var),
  textOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[[var]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(head(mtcars))
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    input[[paste0(var, '_rows_selected')]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]